# Ipython notebook output muted

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I used tqdm in ipython as a way to keep track of progress, however, this has been bothering me for a while, after a few iterations, output cell will print **OUTPUT MUTED**, and the progress bar no longer updates. I was wondering if there's somewhere I could set the output cell to print everything?

```
for i in tqdm(range(len(frd_acct_id_unique))):
    ...

output cell:
|#---------| 694/6146  11% [elapsed: 01:16 left: 10:04,  9.02 iters/sec]**OUTPUT MUTED**
```

Comment: Found the reason for my own problem - I installed IPython-notebook-extensions, one of them is limit_output, just turn it off or change the number of characters allowed.

Comment: Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jupyter/nbextensions, you could configure limit output. I just simply turned it off.

[image]